# How to create a two action in one function (keypress and click)

Tags: jquery

I have a function that on click of a button the function in jquery will run. i also want to add another action , the "Enter" key. Here is my code

```
<input type=text id=search> <button id=searchbtn>Search</button>
```

and my jquery is only for the button. how can i also add the enter key? on the input text?

```
$(' #searchbtn ').click(function(){
some action
}
```

onkeypress? how? click and keypress in one function?

EDIT: I've tried the following but it doesn't appear to work:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  ///search this table 
  $(' #search ').click(function(){ 
    Search(); 
  });

  $( '#emp_search ').keypress(function(e){ 
    if(e.which == 13) { 
      Search(); 
    } 
  }

  function Search(){ alert('test');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of requiring 'one function', instead call the same function with two handlers:

```
$(' #searchbtn ').click(function(){
   someAction();
}

$(' #searchbtn ').keypress(function(){
   someAction();
}
```

Edit: at least two things are wrong with your snippet

- change `Function` to `function`
- define the `Search` function before
  your handlers

Comment: it doesnt seems to work.. here it is. 

   $(document).ready(function(){
   
    ///search this table
    $(' #search ').click(function(){
     Search();
    });
    
    $( '#emp_search ').keypress(function(e){
     if(e.which == 13) {
        //search
        Search();
     }
    }
    
    function Search(){
    alert('test');

Comment: @Vincent you should edit your question with that code and refer to it, it's too hard to read that inline.

Comment: @Vincent your `Search` function needs to be defined BEFORE your handlers. Also, it's convention to use camelcase for function names, e.g. `search` or `searchTheTable`.

Answer (score 1):

Use for your textbox, not for button,

```
$(#searchtext).keypress(function(e) {
    if(e.which == 13) {
       //search
       Search();
    }
});

$(' #searchbtn ').click(function(){
    Search();
}
Function Search()
{
//do anything you want
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a function for the shared code. You can pass that function directly to the click() handler (no need to wrap it in yet-another function), and for the keypress event handler, wrap it in a function that will check the key code, and conditionally call the shared function.

```
function sharedFunction() {
    /* Some common action */
}

// Your current handler
$('#searchbtn').click(sharedFunction);

// The new handler to catch the 'enter' key.
$('#searchtext').keypress(function(event) {
    if(event.keyCode == 13){
        sharedFunction();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use .on for binding a function to multiple events.

```
$(' #searchbtn ').on('click keypress', function() {
// some action
});
```

Comment: where is the tag for the textbox? #search